# No active messages found on that post? Why do I care, exactly?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools

When using the moderation tools, you may find yourself staring at this popup:

[image: No active messages found on that post herpderp]

This can be caused by a few things; you might have closed out the flag by clicking on the post and dealing with it directly (rather than via the mod dashboard) or another moderator may have already dismissed the flag.

My question is... Who <strike>gives a flying</strike> cares if no active messages were found on that post?

If no active messages are found on a post, it means the post has already been dealt with by you or another mod, so informing us of this fact (and leaving the post in the list of active flags) is pointless.

If a moderator tries to dismiss a flag as valid or invalid, and that post has no flag on it, quietly swallow this fact and remove the post from the moderation dashboard.  Please don't throw up an orange rectangle, make us click on it, and leave the offending post cluttering up the flag list.

---

I just wanted to add that this issue is really pissing me off today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the nature of how this panel works, and the volume of flags on SO daily...we completely agree, this is just an annoyance...one that will be removed in the next build.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, I can understand that it's annoying to deal with that kind of thing.

On the other hand, your alternative gives a false impression that you did something. For example, if you choose to valid-dismiss something that actually got invalid-dismissed, and it just silently consumed the flag, then you'd be misled to thinking you valid-dismissed the flag.

I think the better part would be meeting halfway - keep the message to indicate the essence "This got resolved so your action isn't getting carried out", but consequently remove the post from the lineup at the same time. Could use an alternative to the orange box as some sort of smaller message on a collapsed post, like when you delete from the dashboard.

Comment: (wth, I can't add a comment!) Still, the fact is that the only way you end up seeing this is that the flag was taken care of; half the time because some other mod did it and the other half because you couldn't act on the flag from the moderation list.  Honestly, I don't care whether or not I was the one to deal with a flag; it doesn't do my ego any good to know that YES! it was ME! that dismissed that flag.  Its useless information and interferes with the task of moderation.  Fie on that.

Comment: @Will I don't particularly care about *who* took care of the flag, but *how* it got resolved. When your action does something or does *not* do something, there should really be a difference. The interface should not make them exactly the same.

Comment: @GraceNote: Then you should be outraged, *outraged!* that dismissing an offensive flag twice doesn't result in the same behavior.  (well, maybe not outraged; perhaps slightly upset?)

Comment: @Will I'm not actually sure how you can actually dismiss an offensive flag twice. Maybe redismiss an offensive flag, or dismiss something that got reflagged, but I don't think the system allows a singular flag to be dismissed multiple times. At least, not since the fix.

Comment: @GraceNote: Actually, you can.  Open up the mod tools in two different tabs.  Dismiss the flag in both; that's the behavior I'd like to see.

Comment: @Will That doesn't actually double-dismiss, does it?

Comment: @GraceNote: It exhibits the behavior I'm looking for--the second dismissal behaves exactly like the first.  The flag is dismissed and the post is removed from the list.  It does not throw up a box explaining there is no flag to be dismissed, it does not leave the flag in the mod list... it just removes it.  Poof.

Comment: @Will If that's the case, I guess I would find that inconsistent with how most of the site operates. Not outrage worthy, but definitely inconsistent.

Comment: YEAH!  IN UR FACE!  WOOOOT!